# There is Postgresql syntax error at or near ",". But I don't know why it happened

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-colaboratory

table: kusdk.nps is

```
CREATE TABLE kusdk.nps (
  id INT NOT NULL primary key,
  created_at timestamp,
  score smallint
);

id  created_at  score
2   2023-01-02 03:47:26 9
4   2023-01-04 05:02:11 10
5   2023-01-04 18:02:53 1
7   2023-01-05 13:45:47 0
9   2023-01-05 22:36:38 6
10  2023-01-06 13:22:47 10
...
```

```
%%sql
WITH temp AS
(
    SELECT  SUBSTRING(created_at, 1, 10) AS timestamp, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN score >= 9 THEN id END) AS Good,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN score <= 6 THEN id END) AS Bad, ROUND((Good - Bad) * 100 / (Good + Bad), 2) AS nps
    FROM    kusdk.nps
    GROUP BY  timestamp
    ORDER BY  timestamp
)
SELECT timestamp, nps
FROM   temp
LIMIT 10;
```

There is error syntax error at or near "," in Line 10 (SELECT timestamp, nps)

```
%%sql
WITH temp AS
(
    SELECT  SUBSTRING(created_at, 1, 10) AS timestamp, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN score >= 9 THEN id END) AS Good,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN score <= 6 THEN id END) AS Bad, ROUND((Good - Bad) * 100 / (Good + Bad), 2) AS nps
    FROM    kusdk.nps
    GROUP BY  timestamp
    ORDER BY  timestamp
)
SELECT nps, timestamp
FROM   temp
LIMIT 10;

nps timestamp
55  2023-01-01
63  2023-01-02
67  2023-01-03
64  2023-01-04
66  2023-01-05
70  2023-01-06
68  2023-01-07
69  2023-01-08
69  2023-01-09
70  2023-01-10
...
```

But if I changed the position of attribute (SELECT nps, timestamp) it works well.

I don't know why the first code doesn't work.

How can I make the first code work?

I learned SQL with MySQL. So I don't know the exact postgresql sql grammer. I did search the postgresql grammer, but I can't find anything about my code

Comment: @slothrop, Postgresql doesn't have timestamp as reserved, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words

Comment: You can't reference a column defined in the same select clause, i.e. good and bad.

Comment: Just as an fyi, the ORDER BY in your CTE doesn’t do anything. If you want the first 10 records by timestamp then you would need the ORDER BY in the final SELECT statement

Comment: Thanks to your comments, but I just want to know the difference (SELECT timestamp, nps) with (SELECT nps, timestamp)

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Please double check you can run your given query with your given CREATE TABLE statement and get the reported error, because I can't.  I get other errors.

Comment: What is '%%sql'?  Are you even using postgresql?  That looks like something else.

Comment: @jjanes, `%%sql` is from [ipython-sql](https://pypi.org/project/ipython-sql/).

Comment: Second @jjanes comment, the queries have issues before you ever get to `SELECT timestamp, nps`: 1) This `SUBSTRING(created_at, 1, 10)` fails. 2) This `ROUND((Good - Bad)` does not work. As mentioned in previous comment you can't reference an alias like that. Provide a query that fixes those issues as update to your question.

Comment: I just read your all comments. First, I used postgresql. %%sql is used on colab - redshift.  Second, all the code is same except (SELECT timestamp, nps). If there are problems in WITH clause, second query(SELECT nps, timestamp) won't work, but it works well

Comment: But redshift is *not* postgresql.  They are different things.  They forked off almost 20 years ago, and a lot has changed in each since then.